# I want to use my variable from one class on another class in Java

Tags: java

I've been going back and forward on how to deal with this. I have been trying to take input from user in GradesApp.java and store in my variable "gradesPossible" then pass it to another class Grades.java. I don't mind if it is the same name variable or different. I was trying to use setter or getter method, but I am not very familiar with it.

GradesApp.java :

```
public class GradesApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.print("Enter the total points possible for the class: ");
int gradesPossible = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```

I want to access "gradesPossible" in Grades.java

Grades.java:

```
public class Grades {

public double gradesFor3Classes()
    {
    double grade1 = (gradesPossible*3);
    return grade1;
    }
```

Edited typos

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do with value of the gradesPossible? If you want to calculate the value, maybe it's something like this:

```
public class GradesApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter the total points possible for the class: ");
        int gradesPossible = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

        Grades grades = new Grades();
        double gradeResult = grades.calculateGrade(gradesPossible);

        System.out.print("Value Grade: " + gradeResult);

    }

}
```

And this is for Grades class

```
public class Grades {

    public double calculateGrade(int gradesPossible) {
        double grade1 = (gradesPossible*3);
        return grade1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!